# Is there a method in Java for getting the circumference of a given latitude?

Tags: java, gis, latitude-longitude

The circumference of the Earth's latitudes vary per increase/decrease of the latitude. I searched around and found [this page](http://home.online.no/~sigurdhu/Grid_1deg.htm) which shows a table of circumferences of Earth on a given latitude. Is there a library or a method we can use for this on Java?

It would be something like `getCircumference(float latitude)`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a math question, not a programming question.

Comment: If you need the formula to do the calculation, the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have the formula, you should show some attempt to use it.

Comment: I've edited the post for better description.

Answer (score 1):

This function seems to do the job:

```
public static double getCircumference(double lat)
{
    double earthDiameter = 6378.137;
    double earthRadiusPolar = 6356.752314;
    double c = Math.cos((lat/180.0) * Math.PI);
    c = c * earthDiameter;
    c = Math.pow(c, 2);
    double s = Math.sin((lat/180.0) * Math.PI);
    s = s * earthRadiusPolar;
    s = Math.pow(s, 2);
    double res = Math.pow(c + s, 0.5);
    res = Math.pow(earthDiameter, 2) / res;
    return 2 * Math.PI * Math.cos((lat/180.0) * Math.PI) * res;
}
```

It's based on the JavaScript [on this page](http://www.easysurf.cc/circle.htm) and returns the results on the page you linked to.